# Directive drag-and-drop в Angular добавляет символы к расширению файла

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-n-drop, angular-directive

Есть обычная drag-and-drop  директива в Angular.
Все работает хорошо, но только срабатывает не всегда.
Временами в evt.dataTransfer.files[0]?.name приходит или undefined или измененное расширение файла, например,
если перетаскивается файл image1.jpeg
то в event имя image1.jpeg0:-9:478:21

Непонятно, что это и откуда 0:-9:478:21 добавляется.
Последние цифры всегда одни и те-же 478:21, меняются только первые знаки.
И такое только в Chrome.
В Firefox пока такого поведения не замечал.

Рабочий пример тут
https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-upload-drag-n-drop-hye6lv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#eee';
    this.borderColor = '#696D7D';
    this.borderStyle = '2px dashed';
    debugger;
    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]?.name); // undefined or  
                                                  // image1.jpeg0:-9:478:21
    let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    let valid_files : Array<File> = files;
    this.filesChangeEmiter.emit(valid_files);
  }
}
```